# find a path in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I need to find a path in array of objects, but I don't have any idea how to do it.

```
let path = ["1", "5", "7", "2"];
let successPath = [];
```

```
const possibleWays = [
    {
        number: "2",
        canBeNext: [
            {
                number: "3",
                canBeNext: [
                    number: "5",
                    canBeNext: [
                        {
                            number: "9"
                        }
                    ]
            },
            {
                number: "6",
                canBeNext: [
                    {
                        number: "2",
                        canBeNext: [
                            {
                                number: "7"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        number: "6",
                        canBeNext: [
                            {
                                number: "6"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        number: "1",
        canBeNext: [
            {
                number: "5",
                canBeNext: [
                    number: "7",
                    canBeNext: [
                        {
                            number: "9"
                        }
                    ]
            },
            {
                number: "5",
                canBeNext: [
                    {
                        number: "2",
                        canBeNext: [
                            {
                                number: "7"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        number: "6",
                        canBeNext: [
                            {
                                number: "5"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        number: "1",
        canBeNext: [
            {
                number: "1",
                canBeNext: [
                    number: "5",
                    canBeNext: [
                        {
                            number: "1"
                        }
                    ]
            },
            {
                number: "5",
                canBeNext: [
                    {
                        number: "2",
                        canBeNext: [
                            {
                                number: "7"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        number: "7",
                        canBeNext: [
                            {
                                number: "2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

`successPath` will be empty if `path` does not exist in `possibleWays`.

When only one path was found: `successPath[0] = <theRightPath>`

When more then one path was found: `successPath[i] = <theRightPath>`

`successPath` is the same as `path` so if only one path was found in current example:

`successPath[0] = ["1", "5", "7", "2"]`

Thanks for any help or any hint!

Comment: Seems like you're going to want to use recursion here, since it's a tree structure.

Comment: Yeah, It seems, but I don't have any idea how to build the function.

Comment: Well, first let's solve the simpler case where you're just trying to find any success path, not all of them:

```function findSuccessPath(curPath, curNode){
  //base case: what should we do when we reach the bottom of a tree?

  //recursive step: if we're in a middle node, how should we decide whether or not to recurse?

}```

Comment: I think I have to save every point where I reach the right `number`. And go through every path after it and if don't find anything, back to the nearest `reach point` and go through every path before it. And again, and again.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much!

Comment: I cannot do that. Could you please me give some example? It blows my mind.

Comment: `possibleWays` is not a valid js object/array